# Help needed to construct a SQL query

Tags: mysql

Need your help to get the list of suggested friends (who aren't friends of the current user but are friends of 2 or more of the current user's friends). The primary ordering should put people at the same school at the top, and the secondary ordering should put people with more common friends (that is, the number of people who are friends of that person and the current user) near the top.

**Users:**
user_id PK, 
user_name

**Profiles**:
user_id PK,
school_name,
...

**Friendships**:
id PK,
user_id FK,
friend_id FK

Thank you in advance.

Joe

This is not a homework question. I am currently working on a site and my solution seems not efficient enough. That's why I need you suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I started to answer, but I am not sure that I got the question correct.  At any rate, a) Is this homework, and are you looking for HOW to do it or are you asking for code, and b) Can you rephrase, just to make sure it is clear?

Comment: Is this a homework question?  If so, some recommended guidelines: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Could you please post your current solution? That will show that you actually thought about the problem before posting, and will make understanding your model easier.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>(I'm assuming HW here.)</strike>

Seems like if you queried for a list of all of your friends' friends, and checked for the friends-of-friends that weren't unique in that list, you'd be getting somewhere.